# How to call wso2 esb proxy service from wso2 esb schedular

Tags: proxy, wso2, scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb

I want to invoke a proxy service through a scheduled task, following is my scheduler,

```
public class SchedularTask implements Task, ManagedLifecycle {

    /**
     * Synapse environment.
     */
    private SynapseEnvironment synapseEnvironment;

    /**
     * Endpoint Url.
     */
    private String endPointUrl;

    /**
     * Phone number.
     */
    private String phoneNumber;

    /**
     * License key.
     */
    private String licenseKey;

    /**
     * Initializing the Life cycle.
     */
    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment synapseEnvironmentParam) {
        this.synapseEnvironment = synapseEnvironmentParam;
    }

    /**
     * Executing the task.
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        MessageContext messageContext = synapseEnvironment
                .createMessageContext();
        messageContext.setProperty("phoneNumber", this.phoneNumber);
        messageContext.setProperty("licenseKey", this.licenseKey);
        messageContext.setTo(new EndpointReference(endPointUrl));
        synapseEnvironment.injectMessage(messageContext);
    }

    /**
     * Destroying.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    /**
     * @return the endPointUrl
     */
    public final String getEndPointUrl() {
        return endPointUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @param endPointUrl
     *            the endPointUrl to set
     */
    public final void setEndPointUrl(final String endPointUrl) {
        this.endPointUrl = endPointUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @return the phoneNumber
     */
    public final String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param phoneNumber
     *            the phoneNumber to set
     */
    public final void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the licenseKey
     */
    public final String getLicenseKey() {
        return licenseKey;
    }

    /**
     * @param licenseKey
     *            the licenseKey to set
     */
    public final void setLicenseKey(final String licenseKey) {
        this.licenseKey = licenseKey;
    }

}
```

And I passed the endpoinUrl as `http://{ip}:8290/services/a` which is the endpoint of a proxy service named `a`.

But I couldn't find any custom logs in esb console, which I have placed in in-sequence of the proxy service, (This means the proxy service is not hit)
But there's a log for the scheduled task as follows in esb console

```
[2015-03-21 18:15:18,934]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://{ip}:8290/services/a, MessageID: urn:uuid:c527c357-564f-4b58-804e-54e8e7a6a3f5, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

And also I tried use logging in scheduler, I tried log4j and apache commons, but it didn't work. Is there any configuration to activate logging.

Answer (score 0):

You could check below sample scheduler task with a proxy.

```
 <task name="SampleInjectToProxyTask"
         class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
         group="synapse.simple.quartz">
      <trigger count="5" interval="5"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="soapAction"
                value="getQuote"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="format"
                value="soap11"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="injectTo"
                value="proxy"/>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
         <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
            <m0:request>
               <m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol>
            </m0:request>
         </m0:getQuote>
      </property>
      <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
                name="proxyName"
                value="testProxy"/>
   </task>

 <proxy name="testProxy"
          transports="https http"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="disable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <inSequence>
          <send >
            <endpoint key="StockQuoteEpr"/> 
          </send>
         </inSequence>
      </target> 
   </proxy>

<endpoint name="StockQuoteEpr">
     <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
 <sequence name="main">
      <in>
         <log level="full"/>
         <filter source="get-property('To')" regex="http://localhost:9000.*">
            <send/>
         </filter>
      </in>
      <out>
         <send/>
      </out>
      <description>The main sequence for the message mediation</description>
   </sequence>
   </endpoint>
```